# Create field with formula for metrics in bar report

Tags: looker-studio

How can I solve this problem? I don't know if the way I'm doing it is correct.

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

| ID | Proyecto | Informador | Asignada a | Prioridad | Severidad | Reproducibilidad | Versión del producto | Categoría | Fecha de envío | SO | Versión de SO | Plataforma | Visibilidad | Actualizada | Resumen | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10631 | Iron Mountain Perú | Alejandra | Cerrar Incidente | urgente | mayor | no se ha intentado |  | Soporte | 2023-03-02 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-07 | liberar espacio en calipso LINUX Peru Produccion - perucalipp01 | cerrada |
| 10636 | Iron Mountain COLOMBIA - SOPORTE | Alejandra | Cerrar Incidente | normal | menor | no se ha intentado |  | General | 2023-03-06 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-07 | dejar en predocumento el documento bajo el ID (INV100311113677) FBT-263001. | cerrada |
| 10611 | Iron Mountain COLOMBIA - SOPORTE | Alejandra | Cerrar Incidente | normal | mayor | no se ha intentado |  | General | 2023-02-21 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-14 | Verificar informacioon que se envia a Dispapeles en la columna descripcion que genera problemas en el formato de impresion | resuelta |
| 10687 | Iron Mountain Argentina Soporte | Alejandra | Mario | normal | menor | no se ha intentado |  | Soporte | 2023-03-29 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-29 | Solicitud revision tarifario AK850 | asignada |
| 10686 | Iron Mountain Argentina Soporte | Alejandra | Mario | normal | menor | no se ha intentado |  | Soporte | 2023-03-29 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-29 | Liberar espacio en calipso windows 16 - calipso remitos argentina | asignada |
| 10677 | Iron Mountain Perú | Miguel | Hidalgo | normal | mayor | no se ha intentado |  | Soporte | 2023-03-21 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-28 | Copiar facturas a buzon propio en interfaz con TCI | asignada |
| 10660 | Iron Mountain Perú | Miguel | Alejandra | urgente | mayor | no se ha intentado |  | Soporte | 2023-03-15 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-28 | Error en codigo de cliente enviado a TCI | asignada |
| 10685 | Iron Mountain COLOMBIA - SOPORTE | Alejandra | Alejandra | normal | menor | no se ha intentado |  | General | 2023-03-28 |  |  |  | público | 2023-03-28 | Están confirmando las facturas, pero esta no tiene los archivos de la misma (pdf y xml) | asignada |

In DataStudio's bar graph, I would like to filter by date how many tickets were opened and closed through the metrics. In the worksheet I have the "state" column that has the options (cerrado, resuelta, asignada)

[image: Imagem1]

For the metrics I created two new fields as shown in the image.
Inserting the formulas Status in ("cerrada", "resuelta") for Closed and Status = "asignada" para Opened does not generate error in the formula

[image: Image2]

In the report, when I filter by date that I use, the field "Fecha de envío" of the spreadsheet by the date 2023-03-29 should count 2 as "asigned" which is Opened in the graph and 0 as Closed. But whatever date I select the amount of Opened and Closed are always the same.

[image: Imagem3]

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks to be in the formulas for 'Opened' and 'Closed'. While technically correct, they are not telling Looker Studio to specifically take an action. Please try the below formula options!

For the formula 'Closed':

```
CASE WHEN Status IN ("resuelta","cerrada") THEN "Closed" END
```

[Example of the Closed formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRrHc.png)

Alternatively, when you only have one value to look up, you can use contains_text() function as below for 'Opened' formula:

```
CASE
WHEN contains_text(Status,"asignada") THEN "Open"
END
```

[Example of the Open formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9CBQ.png)

For reference, the above functions are IF/THEN statements, asking looker the following:

In the CASE WHEN the field ‘Status’ contains either “resuelta" OR “cerrada" THEN return the value “Closed”, END the formula.

In the CASE WHEN the field 'Status' contains the text "asignada" THEN return the value "Open", END the formula

Comment: Mike, thank you very much for your answer. I managed to solve the problem by including this formula

IF(Status = "assigned","Opened",null)

If(Status in ("closed","result"), 'Closed',null)

Actually the formula I was using wasn't giving an error but it wasn't recognizing it in Looker Studio.

I believe that using "Case When" would also solve.